# Usar progress bar en andrpod

Tags: android, android-studio

Muy buenas necesito ayuda, dentro de mi proyecto esta una barra de progreso la cual al pasar entre activities esta barra de progreso del inicio se llenara con un porcentaje.

***** Ejemplo ***** 
Boton dia 1 **" Barra de progreso "**
Completar 3 actividades 
 1. Correr
 2. saltar
 3. Descanso

Explicare mas detalladamente 
La barra de progreso estara en **0%** Hasta que no se complete las actividades, 
las actividades estan definidas por activities, cuando se culmine la primera actividad de correr **aplastara un boton** (Se cargaria un porcentaje en la barra de progreso) y pasara a la siguiente activity y si completa (sumara al porcentaje ya puesto en la primera actividad) y asi hasta acabar todo y cuando acabe de realizar las tres actividades volvera a la pantalla de inicio y la barra de progreso aparecera con 100%.

**Dentro del caso que no se complete las actividades o se completen 2 de 3** la barra de progreso en el inicio debera mostrar solo el porcentaje de lo que a realizado.

Muchas Gracias de antemano.

Comment: Por qué no colocas el código que llevas realizado hasta el momento?

Comment: Hola franzsebasa, te saludo y te doy la bienvenida al sitio!, te invito a realizar el [tour] para 
conocer el funcionamiento básico del sitio y obtener tu primera 
[medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Con respecto a la realización de preguntas que estas sean bien recibidas por la comunidad y obtengas excelentes respuestas, **es muy importante leer [ask]**,saludos.